Go Assembler Named Constants
Is there a way to name constant values in Go Assembly? I'd like to name some constants to make my code more readable.
I am looking for something that works like #define in C or .equ in Arm64 assembly. Here's an example of what I'd do in those languages:
C
#define myConstant 2024
Arm64
.equ myConstant, 2024
I've tried using #define in Go Assembly, but I can only get it to work for entire instructions. Here's an example of that:
#define MyInstruction     MOVD R1, R2
#define OtherInstruction  WORD $0xaabbccee

When I try to just make and use #define with a constant this happens:
Code
#define myConstant        WORD $2024
MOVD    R1, myConstant(R0)

Compiler Error

myFile:49: expected '(', found $
asm: assembly of myFile.s failed



The Go assembler runs a variant of the C preprocessor on your code.  I.e. what you define with #define will literally be searched and replaced in your code.  So if you write
#define myConstant        WORD $2024

...

MOVL myConstant, EAX

the result will be something like
MOVL WORD $2024, EAX

which is clearly nonsensical.
To fix this, change your macro to read just
#define myConstant 2024

and use it as if it was a symbol
MOVL $myConstant, EAX


I feel really dumb, thanks! This is the answer

@CorkiMain I'm happy that I was able to help you.  If this resolved your question, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the green check mark.
